# starting Mock Server automatically when running restbird docker container

Tags: rest, docker

i want to use the "Mock Server" feature provided with https://restbird.org/ .

When starting restbird via the provided docker image, it listens on localhost:8080 by default.
Unfortunately the configured "Mock Server" instances still need to be started via the Web Frontend as it is described in the documentation here:

https://restbird.org/docs/mock-run.html#run-mock-server

Is there a way to *automatically* start the "Mock Server" instances when running the docker image without logging in into the backend (via admin/admin) and clicking the "start" button ? 
Reason is, i want to start the mock server inside a gitlab pipeline where i have no further interaction possibilities after the container has been started.

I can not find anything like this in the documentation.

Thanks a lot for any clues - or if it is not possible i cam make a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I  have found the solution myself. One can start a specific Mock Server as described in:

https://restbird.org/docs/API-MockServer.html#start-specific-mockserver-case

This can be scripted into my pipeline after executing the `docker run` command.